# Linux stalled while shutting down---what to do?

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, shutdown, reboot

I tried to reboot a computer running Ubuntu 20.04 (`Linux 5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu`), but it keeps outputting error or warning messages on the black screen and does not shut down. What should I do? Is it good to press the power button for 5 seconds and force it turn off? Or, will it cause any inconsistency in the disk?

The shutdown message started to deviate from the usual one around the following point.

```
[ *** ] A stop job is running for /data (11s / 1min 32s)
[756977.526939] RIP: 0010:release_pages+0x278/0x4e0
[756977.527758] Code: b8 49 8d 7f 50 e8 ......
[756977.528654] RSP: 0018:ffff......
[756977.529559] RAX: dead000000000122 RBX: 0000......
 :
 :
[ OK ] Unmounted /data
[ OK ] Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[ OK ] Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-label/......
[ OK ] Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[ OK ] Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
       Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots, etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[ OK ] Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[ OK ] Stopped Create System Users.
[ OK ] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[ OK ] Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[ OK ] Reached target Shutdown.
[ OK ] Reached target Final Step.
[ OK ] Finished Reboot.
[ OK ] Reached target Reboot.
[756977.819522] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[757007.823383] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices - timeed out, issuing SIGKILL to PID 382289.
[757007.827668] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[757007.831640] systemd-journald[377]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[757017.831895] systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: (sd-sync)
[757097.831617] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining remaining processes...
[757097.842836] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to PID 382289 ((sd-sync)).
[757107.844080] systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: (sd-sync)
[757187.849840] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[757187.854008] [382290]: Remounting '/' read-only in with options 'errors=remount-ro'.
[757188.790620] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode:none.
```

Here `......` means that I omitted the rest of the line, and two vertical `:`s means that several lines were omitted.

The screen continued running. It is currently repeating to emit chucks of message similar (but slightly changing) as following:

```
[762469.371157] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
[762469.371816] rcu: $0-...0: (130 GPs behind) idle=689/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=7399238/7399238 fqs=650925
[762469.372457] $(detected by 2, t=1320148 jiffies, g=23438573, q=695)
[762469.373098] Sending NMI from CPU 2 to CPUs 0:
[762469.373730] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
[762469.373731] CPU: 0 PID: 382290 Comm: (sd-remount) Tainted: G    B D    OE    5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu
[762469.373732] Hardware name: LENOVO ........
[762469.373733] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x79/0x230
[762469.373734] Code: 7c f0 0f ba 2b 08 0f ......
[762469.373735] RSP: 0018:ffff........
[762469.373736] RAX: 00000000......
 :
 :
[762469.373743] Call Trace:
[762469.373743]  <TASK>
[762469.373744]  _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x3b/0x50
[762469.373745]  lock_page_lruvec_irqsave+0x62/0x90
[762469.373747]  release_pages+0x264/0x4e0
[762469.373749]  __pagevec_release+0x30/0x70
[762469.373750]  __invalidate_mapping_pages+0x201/0x270
[762469.373752]  ? __wait_for_common+0xf7/0x160
[762469.373756]  invalidate_mapping_pages+0x10/0x20
[762469.373757]  invalidate_bdev+0x5b/0x60
[762469.373759]  reconfigure_super+0x12d/0x240
[762469.373761]  path_mount+0x969/0xa70
[762469.373762]  ? putname+0x57/0x70
[762469.373764]  do_mount+0x80/0xa0
[762469.373766]  __x64_sys_mount+0x8b/0xe0
[762469.373768]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
[762469.373769]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
[762469.373770] RIP: 0033:0x7f07bc......
[762469.373771] Code: 48 8b 0d 15 c2 0c 00 ......
[762469.373772] RSP: 002b:00007ffd......
[762469.373773] RAX: ffffffff......
 :
 :
[762469.373777]  </TASK>
```

Comment: When a shutdown hangs I poweroff. I've been doing that for years and years and as a home user I have never had a problem.  Working a production server with many connections you have more to think about but as a home user just go ahead and pull the plug.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered there were those [Magic SysRq keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). While holding down both <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd> and SysRq (<kbd>Prt Scn</kbd>) keys, I pressed <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd> one by one.

I saw a message like

```
This SysRq key is disabled.
```

or something like that for <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, and <kbd>I</kbd>. Then, different messages appeared for <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd>.
After <kbd>B</kbd>, the computer rebooted.

After the reboot, the computer operates normally at least for the time being. I still don't know what the error was. I would be glad if someone could post a proper answer.

- [Magic SysRq keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)
- [REISUB - the gentle Linux restart](https://blog.kember.net/posts/2008-04-reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power